# Read Node OpcUa to JsonObject

Tags: c#, opc-ua

I have an Opc client, when I read the node is ExtensionObject.

the node is custom structure in Opc Ua Server PLC siemens 1500.

the value is systematically encoded as a byte.

In the example provided, the node is read with an Xml encoding.

I tried to specify to the client not to use the Binary encoding with :

```
ConfiguredEndpoint endpoint = new ConfiguredEndpoint(null, endpointDescription, endpointConfiguration);
endpoint.Configuration.UseBinaryEncoding = false;
```

This changes nothing.

I Have try this:

```
DataValue value = _session.ReadValue(nodeId);
ExtensionObject extObject = (ExtensionObject)value.Value;
var Decoder = new BinaryDecoder(extObject.Body as Byte[], ServiceMessageContext.GlobalContext);
var Result = Decoder.ReadXmlElement(null);
return value;
```

> Exception :MaxByteStringLength 1048560 < 54657037

Do you have any idea what I might have missed?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

I try to Use BinaryDecoder and desactivating binary decoder in client.

Comment: I resolverd.  I need install the nuget OPCFoundation.NetStandard.Opc.Ua.Client.ComplexTypes.

I added this to my server connection and the objects are now decoded, so I can watch them being processed and written.
 <
ComplexTypeSystem complexTypeSystem = new ComplexTypeSystem(_session);
complexTypeSystem.Load().Wait();>

Answer (score 0):

**Consider that I use reflection to auto convert the ExtensionObject by passing the required opc type**

In case of single `ExtensionObject`

```
if (value is ExtensionObject extObj)
{
    var type = property.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
    value = extObj.DecodeBinaryValue(type);
}
```

In case of `ExtensionObject[]`

```
if (value is ExtensionObject[] extArr)
{
    var listType = property.GetType().GenericTypeArguments[0];
    var type = listType.GenericTypeArguments[0];
    List<object> tempList = new List<object>();
    for (var index = 0; index < extArr.Length; index++)
    {
        var valueBytes = extArr[index];
        var ext = valueBytes.DecodeBinaryValue(type);
        tempList.Add(Convert.ChangeType(ext, type));
    }

    var castValue = Activator.CreateInstance(listType) as IList;
    foreach (var item in tempList) castValue.Add(item);
    value = castValue;
}
```

Finaly the extesion to convert the ExtensionObject

```
private static object DecodeBinaryValue(this ExtensionObject extensionObject, Type type)
{
    using var decoder = new BinaryDecoder(extensionObject.Body as byte[], ServiceMessageContext.GlobalContext);
    var decodeValue = decoder.ReadEncodeable("", type);
    return decodeValue;
}
```